# Database read-only mode Timestamp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2019 - currently database is in read-only mode. I need to know when it was changed (date timestamp, user)?

Comment: Do you mean when the database was changed to read-only and by whom?

Comment: Unless you have a server level ddl trigger to track this I don't know that there is any way to determine this.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes. I am looking for a way to find the details from log/DMV/others.

Comment: @RamkumarSambandam, the info is logged by the default trace but the retention is limited. How far back do you need to query?

Comment: @DanGuzman last 7 days

Comment: @DanGuzman I was able to retrieve details from the query in the below link, with passing only the database name in the where condition.  
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/234707/who-created-that-table-in-sql-server  thanks for your suggestion about Default trace